# Java JFrame is not visible when I later call a new class

Tags: java

I have a problem. I the main Method I init and add all buttons and Labels, then I set the windows settings and at the end I implement some ActionListener. This part of the code is well working.

But now I'd like to expand the code.
I'd write a new class who wait for a Card (CardControllerIO), to get a BadgeId from a NFC-Card. I can get the ID but the JFrame isn't show recently.

The main from the View-Class:

```
public OverviewView(double Value, String Description, String Beneficiary) {¸
    value = Value;
    beneficiary = Beneficiary;
    description = Description;

    valueText = new JTextField(String.valueOf(value));
    descText = new JTextField(description);

    initElements();
    addElements();
    windowSetting();

    logoutActionListener();
    transactions();
}
```

By transactions() there is a if-loop who wait til a card is connected.
How can I fix this problem?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please edit your answer by adding code for `transactions()`. We need to know how the waiting is implemented. Also, do you set the frame to visible after calling `OverviewView()` or within any of its method calls?